# Add or remove a program in sound menu in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, rhythmbox, music

I had rhythm box in sound menu which come along with Ubuntu 12.04.
In order to have good playlist option i moved to clementine music player.
after installing clementine in the system, sound menu has both the player option.
I tried choosing the default player as clementine in settings. but it do not change anything.
problem is when i try to play any music by selecting inside clementine music player.
rhythm box also started playing the same music.

I guess removing the rhythm box in sound menu may solve the problem.
Please help how to remove or add any app into sound menu in Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.howtogeek.com/113897/how-to-remove-media-players-from-ubuntus-sound-menu-add-your-own/) is a very detailed, yet easily understandable tutorial on how to do it.

It gives both a graphical and command line approach.